# How to integrate a 3rd party library with zf2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm working on a zf2 project which needs to be integrated with a 3rd party library. The library is not compatible with php namespaces.

I found few articles describing the integration of namespace compatible libraries. According to them if the library is compatible with namespaces, then we can integrate it by adding a map into Module.php as follows.

```
'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
    'namespaces' => array(
        'MyLibrary' => __DIR__ .'/path/to/library',
    ),
),
```

I tried with that and then I had to set the namespace for each and every file within the library to be able to work with the library. But it's not a good practice to modify someone else's library.

So, please help me to integrate a non-namespace compatible php library with the zf2

Comment: Classes without a namespace are not 'incompatible' they just need to be handled differently when auto-loading. Are you using composer? If so you can [*autoload* classes that do not have a namespace](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've gone through this article as well. But as I understood psr-0, psr-4 both are describing the namespace autoloading. (correct me if am wrong). So, it was not helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

In your Module.php add a ClassMapAutoloader to the getAutoloaderConfig function.

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig() {
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
        ),
    );
}
```

Then create a autoload_classmap.php at the same level als Module.php that looks like this:

```
return array(
    'MyClass'         => __DIR__ . '/libs/MyClass.php',
);
```

Comment: I have done some work with classmap autoloading. But the problem with this method is there are quite a number of classes within my library. So, If I go through this way, I'll have to add a long list of entries for each and every class file of the library (which also feels me as not a good practice). What I was finding is a method of autoloading all the classes in the library (as we are autoloading a namespace)